# Mongo replica set config

Tags: mongodb, replication, mongodb-replica-set

I configured a 3 node replica set and uninstalled mongo when my virtual memory limit exceeded then as i was starting my mongo replication I couldn't get these commands to work.

```
rs.initiate()
rs.reconfig()//with config params
```

My previous replica set has `primary(27017)`,`secondary(27018,27019)`
After reinstalling I could get secondary to work but my primary is saying

> no replica set conf has been found.

I don't understand what actually happened.
Either I miss some files or mongo wants me to learn more about it.
Please need advice asap.

Comment: Try `rs.status();` and let me know what it gives.

Answer (score 0):

`rs.initiate` requires a config document. Give it that while calling rs.initiate.

```js
config = {
_id : "name_of_replica_set", members : [
    { _id : 0, host : "localhost:27017" },
    { _id : 1, host : "localhost:27018" },
    { _id : 2, host : "localhost:27019" }
    ]
};
rs.initiate(config);
```

Try this and see if it works for you.

Comment: Why should that be necessary? The replica set still is there and basically only a new member was added.

Comment: I don't find him mentioning anything about the addition of a new member. But then he mentioned that he is able to connect to the secondaries. So he should definitely be able to connect to primary. I suggested this because the error message was about the absence of configuration.

Comment: Read closely: "I got my __secondary__ to work". He removed the old primary and then set that up again. Only the primary. And the other machines still build a replica set of two members. Now, what would it be called to have the newly set up machine and the remaining replica set build a new one?

Comment: Markus is right.I reinstalled mongo and started secondaries as they are with command supplying dbpath,port and replicaset name.But when i did rs.status i got primary gone and there's no way i can get that back and then the secondaries went into RECOVERING.

Comment: I did what you said siddharth.Still no luck.I'll post the output here.